# jq - reformat the JSON and put values as keys into new array and objects?

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, group-by, jq

How can I reformat the JSON, create a new array based on selection criteria and by and put values as keys?

Here is one fragment of the json file:

```
[
    {
        "Header": {
            "Tenant": "Tenant1"
        },
        "Body": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "ca95",
                    "name": "Property1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "b126",
                    "name": "Property2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "aec0",
                    "name": "Property3"
                },
                {
                    "id": "a62b",
                    "name": "Property4"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Header": {
            "Tenant": "Tenant2"
        },
        "Body": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "ca95",
                    "name": "Property1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "b4cd",
                    "name": "Property4"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Values for the keys `Header.Tenant` and `Body.values[].name` are unique, but for the  `Body.values[].id` are not - for the *Property4* corresponding `"id"` from the same object is *a62b* for the *Tenant1* and *b4cd* for the *Tenant2*.

I need to find out for the particular `"name/Property"` key/value how many different corresponding `"id"` and `"Tenant"` exist and group them by the value of `"id"` instead.

The result should look like the following:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Property1",
        "ca95": [
            "Tenant1",
            "Tenant2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Property2",
        "b126": [
            "Tenant1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Property3",
        "aec0": [
            "Tenant1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Property4",
        "a62b": [
            "Tenant1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Property4",
        "b4cd": [
            "Tenant2"
        ]
    }
]
```

How can this be done with jq? I guess I should use group_by and/or reduce?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more efficient solution than is possible using `group_by`. It uses `GROUPS_BY`, which is a stream-oriented generalization of `group_by`:

```
# Emit a stream of arrays, each corresponding to a group
# defined by f, which can be any jq filter
# that maps every item in the stream to a single value.
def GROUPS_BY(stream; f): 
   reduce stream as $x ({};
     ($x|f) as $s
     | ($s|type) as $t
     | (if $t == "string" then $s else ($s|tojson) end) as $y
     | .[$t][$y] += [$x] )
   | select(.)
   | .[][] ;
```

The solution can now be written in a straightforward manner without further recourse to `reduce`:

```
[ GROUPS_BY(.[]
            | .Header.Tenant as $tenant
            | .Body.values[] | {name, id, tenant: $tenant};
            {name,id}) 
  | (.[0] | { name }) + { (.[0].id): map(.tenant) } ]
```

Comment: you are a genius. And yes, your solutions are way above my pay grade.

One follow-up question - how should I use the above in a shell script the safest/most elegant way? It is ahem... 100 char long a single line. Should I assign it to a shell var and then assign that var to jq var? Or to put it in a separate file as a .jq filter and call it?

Comment: There are three sensible ways that I can think of: (1) use jq '....' over multiple lines in a shell script; (2) use the -f option; (3) use jq's support for modules. The last option is the most tricky but when one has "standard library" functions (such as GROUPS_BY), it might be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess I should use group_by and/or reduce?

It can be done quite easily with just `group_by` and `map`:

```
map(.Header.Tenant as $tenant
    | .Body.values[] | {name, id, tenant: $tenant})
| group_by(.name)
| map(group_by(.id))
| map( .[] |  (.[0] | { name }) + { (.[0].id): map(.tenant) })
```

One way to understand this is to run the first two lines of the program, and then the first three lines, and proceeding incrementally from there. You could also add `debug` statements along the way.

Comment: I've tried the above but in the resulting array for the ``Property4`` it groups together ``Tenan1`` and ``Tenant2``, while they should be separate arrays because ``id`` is different.

Comment: Perfect! Works as well and is shorter than the first solution.

Comment: One follow-up comment - if I want to have arrays placed under the new object ``arrays``, then how do you modify the `` map( .[] | (.[0] | { name }) + { (.[0].id): map(.tenant) })`` statement?